# git push impossible due to unpacker error

Tags: gitlab

can anyone help me please ? I can't push due to :

```
C:\projects\MadmaqsSF>git push origin dev
Enumerating objects: 2125, done.
Counting objects: 100% (2125/2125), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (1473/1473), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2124/2124), 127.61 MiB | 233.35 MiB/s, done.
Total 2124 (delta 539), reused 2047 (delta 494)
remote: error: inflate: data stream error (invalid stored block lengths)
remote: fatal: pack has bad object at offset 43619424: inflate returned -3
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To http://midex/moud/MadmaqsSF.git
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://midex/moud/MadmaqsSF.git'
```

I think it's about long file name..

I tried:

> git push -f origin dev
>
> Its not a permission issue

Comment: Try git push -f origin dev --no-thin

Comment: I tried -f but it doen't work,

Answer (score 0):

Finally i just created a new repository and pushed my work on it. I think the old repo was corrupted.